# jQuery.Load() in asp

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

i have a problem in using jQuery.load()
 i have a page that is a admin Control Panel, this page contains sidebar and this sidebar contains links, that when admin clicked on that links, i want to load the content of target page to admin panel page.
 for example the target page contains textboxes and a button, the admin must enter his or her details and the click on the button to save data database, but when the admin clicked on the saveButton, the page redirected to target page, how can i solve this problem.

i'm a new asp programmer, plz help, TNX.

Comment: May we see your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use JQuery Ajax method, it's very easy and usefull, no need the refresh the page, open the links:)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add an

```
<input type="hidden" value="the-page-you-want-to-target" name="target_page" />
```

before the save button.

Then in your ASP script you can check for

```
Request.QueryString("target_page")
```

and redirect to the right page. At least now you know which page was loaded.

Sometimes we just have to keep it simple ;)